# subprocess.Popen with a unicode path

Tags: python, windows, unicode, command-line, subprocess

I have a unicode filename that I would like to open.
The following code:

```
cmd = u'cmd /c "C:\\Pok\xe9mon.mp3"'
cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

returns

```
>>> 'C:\Pokיmon.mp3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

even though the file do exist. Why is this happening?

Comment: I take it that 'cmd' stands in for something else?

Comment: I removed the double quotes, even though they are not related to the question.

Comment: Have you included the python path to you PATH environment variable?
Assuming your Python installation is in C:\Python25, your new path variable should be :
    %PATH%;C:\Python25

Comment: Yes it does, but what does the `PATH` has to do with anything?

Comment: related: [Unicode filename to python subprocess.call()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2595448/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're using Windows and Python 2.X.  Use [os.startfile](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.startfile(u'Pokémon.mp3')
```

Non-intuitively, getting the command shell to do the same thing is:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import locale
>>> subprocess.Popen(u'Pokémon.mp3'.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding()),shell=True)
```

On my system, the command shell (cmd.exe) encoding is `cp437`, but for Windows programs is `cp1252`.  `Popen` wanted shell commands encoded as `cp1252`.  This seems like a bug, and it also seems fixed in Python 3.X:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('Pokémon.mp3',shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! i didnt know about `os.startfile`.

Comment: On Windows on Python 2, `Popen(u'Pokémon.mp3'.encode(encoding))` works iff `Popen(u'Pokémon.mp3'.encode('mbcs'))` works i.e., it should succeed with `cp1252` and it should fail with `cp437` in your case. Does `shell=True` change it? What are values for `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and `locale.getpreferredencoding()`? In general, `u"é"` might be unrepresentable using `mbcs`. Python 3 uses Unicode API directly.

Comment: On windows on python 2, if you want to use unicode command line (as python 3), you can use [this workaround](http://vaab.blog.kal.fr/2017/03/16/fixing-windows-python-2-7-unicode-issue-with-subprocesss-popen/) leveraging ``ctypes`` to patch ``subprocess.Popen(..)``.

Comment: `os.startfile` works, but `u'Pokémon.mp3'.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())` will of course fail in any locale in which the ANSI codepage doesn't map "é". In 2.x `subprocess.Popen` calls `CreateProcessA`, which decodes the command line as ANSI, so it is limited to commands that can be encoded as such. If you need a command line that can't be encoded as ANSI, then you must do something else via ctypes, cffi, or an extension module, such as call `CreateProcessW` or a CRT function such as `_wsystem`.

Comment: CMD is a Unicode application. It only uses codepages to decode bytes when working with files and pipes, such as reading a line of a batch script or a `for /f` loop that reads stdout from a command. In this case its default codepage is ANSI if it isn't attached to a console. Otherwise it uses the *console's* input or output codepage (CMD is not the console), which defaults to OEM unless changed via chcp.com. In any case, the encoding CMD uses for files is irrelevant. By the time CMD sees its command line, it's already decoded as Unicode by Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved through **smart_str** function of Django module.

Use this code:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
cmd = u'cmd /c "C:\\Pok\xe9mon.mp3"'
smart_cmd = smart_str(cmd)
subprocess.Popen(smart_cmd)
```

You can find information on how to install Django on Windows [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#install-the-django-code).
You can first install [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) and then you can install Django by starting
a command shell with administrator privileges and run this command:

```
pip install Django
```

This will install Django in your Python installation's site-packages directory.

Comment: I won't install a whole new framework just to encode unicode correctly. fix should be one or two lines long, not 1000+ of complex code.

Comment: ok, am sorry, I have updated my answer. Maybe it is more helpful now.

Comment: First, the `latin-1` encoding is not unicode. It won't work with all unicode cases. Second, it's still doesn't work. Try it yourself.

Comment: ok, I work on Linux and I tested it with the `os.popen` it worked..
Maybe for windows doesn't work.. :( I remove my updated part of the answer.

Comment: Someone made a standalone module out of Django smart_str: [smartencoding](https://pypi.org/project/smartencoding/)

Comment: @gaborous that's really helpful! Good idea to isolate and include that functionality in a module. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> subprocess.call(['start', u'avión.mp3'.encode('latin1')], shell=True)
0
```

There's no need to call `cmd` if you use the `shell` parameter
The correct way to launch an associated program is to use the cmd's `start` built-in AFAIK.

My 2c, HIH.

Comment: Thanks for the side note, but this still doesn't fix the unicode problem. This works on your system because your locale MBCS has the ó char. This code won't work on computers that has hebrew or japanese as their locale language.

Answer (score -2):

I think windows uses 16-bit characters, not sure if it's UCS2 or UTF16 or something like that. So I guess that it could have an issue with UTF8.

Comment: setting as 'utf-16' returns `TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str` so i guess thats wrong.