# Python subprocess check_output decoding specials characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, subprocess, special-characters

I'm having some issues with python encoding. When I try to execute this:

```
subprocess.check_output("ipconfig", shell=True)
```

it gives me an output with special characters in it, like:

```
"Statut du m\x82dia"
"M\x82dia d\x82connect\x82"
```

(i'm french)

When I try decoding it with a `.decode()` at the end, it gives me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 78: invalid start byte
```

I tried using `.decode("utf-8")`, I played around with encoding and decoding for hours, and I can't find the answer. Everything I looked on the internet didn't work. Maybe I'm just dumb, but hey.
What can I do to get rid of those decoding errors and get my special characters to be printed?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941064/subprocess-popen-with-a-unicode-path https://bugs.python.org/issue27179

Comment: You could fix it by adding `encoding="437"` or `encoding="850"` to the arguments, but I wouldn't be happy with that answer since it doesn't explain why the codepage is what it is.

Comment: @JoshLee Oh man, with `.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)` it works like a charm! Thanks man! Could you make your answer an "official" answer or something, so I can validate it? Thanks again, you made my day, I've been stuck with this for a long time ^^"

Comment: What Josh Lee said. FWIW, `b"M\x82dia d\x82connect\x82".decode('cp437')` returns `'Média déconnecté'`; you get the same result by decoding with 'cp850'.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for your reply, I'll keep those encoding names in mind ^^

Comment: You should probably use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to get the encoding rather than `sys.stdout.encoding`. There's also `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`, which can be the same as `sys.stdout.encoding`, but it can be different, depending on how your system is set up (I don't use Windows, so I can't give any specific advice).

Comment: @PM2Ring Alright, thanks for the advices!

Comment: There's also `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

Comment: @PM2Ring @JoshLee `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns utf-8, so it does the same error as before, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns "mbcs", I've no idea what it means but it doesn't work , it transforms the `\x82` into `\u201a`, and same with `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, witch returns "cp1252". but it's not important, my question is anwered, thanks to both of you ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're invoking the command through CMD, which has a Unicode mode and an ANSI mode. The "correct" way is to invoke the Unicode mode, but you can add `encoding="437"` or `encoding="850"` to the subprocess call to make it work. This depends on you knowing what the current codepage is.